# Hiring manager added me on LinkedIn after interview

Tags: interviewing, job-search, hiring-process

**Update**:I am shortlisted for  second round interview. HR says I am one of the final two candidates.Fingers crossed! Thank you for the replies.

I sent a thank you note to the hiring manager after an interview. They replied saying they thought I was great, they have 2 more candidates to go through and will move on to second interviews soon. They sent me a LinkedIn connection request after the email and viewed my profile. I was the first candidate they interviewed.

I understand it could just be a company process. Just wanted to know if anyone had similar interview experience before? Do recruiters check every candidate's LinkedIn during the hiring process?

Comment: Well, it's probably not a negative sign. She already told you you were "great". Beyond that, no one on this board can read her mind.

Comment: Yeah that's totally normal. They usually check your Linkedin and they might add you as a contact for future reference.

Comment: Yes, it's very common. You're less likely to lie on your LinkedIn than your resume because your LinkedIn is more likely to be public. They can ask for an informal reference if they know someone from your 1st-degree network. Plus, even if you don't get the job but were a good potential candidate, they may be able to mine your first-degree network.

Comment: That's what linkedin is for

Comment: @stephan I don’t think that’s true, there are an awful lot of exaggerations on LinkedIn!

Comment: @Gaius, That's why I said "less likely". A resume is worse than LinkedIn.

Answer (score 6):

> *I understand it could just be a company process.*

It may be a company process, it may not be. It can be just that individual trying to build network, which is OK and not uncommon.

Do not read too much into it, just let it be.

> *Do recruiters check every candidate's LinkedIn during the hiring process?*

While I cannot say it's a *standard*, checking a candidates LinkedIn (or equivalent) profile is a common practice in my experience. Whether they send a connection request or not, it depends.

Answer (score 3):

> I understand it could just be a company process

Almost certainly is. "Stay positive and keep them on side until we've decided" is likely the name of the game here. They don't want a potential candidate getting cold feet and walking away if they can help it.

The reverse is also true - you should also stay positive, enthusiastic and on-side until (unless) you've definitely decided you *don't* want the job. You don't want them getting cold feet and walking away because you "don't seem that enthusiastic", only for you to decide you'd quite like this job after all.

> Do recruiters check every candidate's LinkedIn during the hiring process?

These days, yes - this is almost universal. (Most will likely do a more thorough search than just checking LinkedIn, too.)