# Is it appropriate to send Linkedin invite after being told it was succesful interview and will go further?

Tags: interviewing, software-development

I was told that the interview is successful and we want to go further with you. After knowing this, is it okay to add interviewers on linkedin after some weeks?

Comment: I'm not sure why someone would down-vote this. It's a legitimate question. I agree with the answer from @helloworld

Comment: There were similar questiuons in the past: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/52341/connecting-with-interviewer-on-linkedin-post-interview https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/115930/should-i-add-interviewer-on-linkedin-before-interview https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/148236/hiring-manager-added-me-on-linkedin-after-interview https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/91264/linkedin-etiquette-after-an-interview-before-starting-new-position

Comment: @BernhardDöbler they do not state if interview is successful or not

Answer (score 11):

No. They already have your CV, so they know who you are. Unless you are offered a job, you don't have too much professional relationship with the interviewers.